# Apply different custom functions to different datasets

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader

Given the below dataset class:

```
class MYDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path):
        df = read_csv(path, header=None, delimiter=r"\s+")
        df = df.iloc[:, 1:-1].values
        self.X = df[:, 1:]
        self.y = df[:, 0]
        self.y = self.y.reshape((len(self.y), 1))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return [self.X[idx], self.y[idx]]
    
    def get_splits(self, n_test=0.3):
        testing_size = round(n_test * len(self.X))
        train_size = len(self.X) - testing_size
        val_size = round(testing_size /2)
        test_size = testing_size - val_size
        return random_split(self, [train_size, val_size, test_size])
    
def prepare_data(path):
    dataset = MYDataset(path)
    train, val, test = dataset.get_splits()
    train_dl = DataLoader(train, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)
    val_dl = DataLoader(val, batch_size=len(val), shuffle=False)
    test_dl = DataLoader(test, batch_size=len(test), shuffle=False)
    return train_dl, val_dl, test_dl
```

and the 2 other custom functions below:

```
  def augment_data(array):
     ...
     return(gen_data)
```

```
  def BINNED(dataframe):
     ...
     return(data_ohe, 0,1)
```

How to apply the function `BINNED` on train, val, and test subsets and apply the function `augment_data` **only** on 'train' subset?

Comment: Could you please explain what function's parameters are? (each function)

Comment: @Phoenix the function augmen_data is usied for data augmentation on the train data, while the BINNED function is used on teain, validation, and test data to put each dataset in bins

Comment: When do you want to apply these functions: when you create the dataset directly, or later after creating the dataset?

Comment: @Phoenix Thank you for your reply!. It should first split the dataset into train, validation, and test sets. Then apply the `augment_data` on the train set only, and apply the `BINNED` on all sets. It should return train set augmented and binned, validation set binned, and test set binned.

Comment: Ok, now I understood your question more.

Comment: I have a question where is the function random_split()? From where did you call when you split the data?

Comment: @Phoenix `from torch.utils.data import random_split`

Comment: You should split the dataset outside. This is how it is done!